# forEach js, choosing objects in array?

Tags: javascript

```
// Complete the below questions using this array:
const array = [
  {
    username: "john",
    team: "red",
    score: 5,
    items: ["ball", "book", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "becky",
    team: "blue",
    score: 10,
    items: ["tape", "backpack", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "susy",
    team: "red",
    score: 55,
    items: ["ball", "eraser", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "tyson",
    team: "green",
    score: 1,
    items: ["book", "pen"]
  },

];
```

---

```
//Create an array using forEach that has all the usernames with a "!" to each of the usernames

const exclamArray = [];
const newArray = array.forEach((username) => {
  exclamArray.push(array.username + '!');
})
console.log('forEach', exclamArray);
```

when i executed the code above, it gave me

`forEach (4) ["undefined!", "undefined!", "undefined!", "undefined!"]`

how can i select the object's value 'username'? have i done anything wrong on that code?

Comment: Use `username`, not `array.username`. Or rather, `(player) => { … player.username … }`. And don't use `forEach`, but `map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of the callback function for `Array.prototype.forEach` is an element, not a property.

Set a variable for element and reference it with `username`. And if you want to save a new array to variable `newArray` by returning value, use a `Array.prototype.map`.

```js
const array = [{
    username: "john",
    team: "red",
    score: 5,
    items: ["ball", "book", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "becky",
    team: "blue",
    score: 10,
    items: ["tape", "backpack", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "susy",
    team: "red",
    score: 55,
    items: ["ball", "eraser", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "tyson",
    team: "green",
    score: 1,
    items: ["book", "pen"]
  },

];
//Create an array using forEach that has all the usernames with a "!" to each of the usernames

const exclamArray = [];
const newArray = array.forEach((element) => {
  exclamArray.push(element.username + '!');
})
console.log('forEach', exclamArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

the `forEach` iterator will pass each element of an array into the executing function. In this case, the arrow function is receiving the element into the variable `username`. Moving forward, in order to access members of that element (since they are all objects), you would use `username.username` (for example, if you wanted to access the username of the object).

Hopefully it is clear that you may want to choose a different name in your arrow function's variable.

As a minor clarification, being that `array` is an array of objects, it does not have a `username` property, and each iteration of the forEach loop reflects `undefined` in the `exclamArray` as a result.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.map()` makes the most sense for collecting the subparts into another array:

```
let usernames = users.map(user => user.username + '!')

["john!", "becky!", "susy!", "tyson!"]
```

Which really makes me wonder if they're wanting you to do the following:

```
users.forEach(user => user.username += '!')

0: {username: "john!", team: "red", score: 5, items: Array(3)}
1: {username: "becky!", team: "blue", score: 10, items: Array(3)}
2: {username: "susy!", team: "red", score: 55, items: Array(3)}
3: {username: "tyson!", team: "green", score: 1, items: Array(2)}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7fq2n0wp/3/

What that does is modify the *original* array usernames by reference.